# What should be done when a non answer has been accepted?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering the other day if Prof. Snape could have healed George's ear, since he was able to heal the cut from Harry's *Sectumsempra*.

I found that the question had already been asked and answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54016/could-georges-ear-have-been-healed-by-snape).

However, the [(then) accepted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/54018/13716) clearly doesn't answer the question, and is simply stating what the OP in the question wanted to find the reason for.

If I ask whether Snape would have been able to heal George's ear, it will almost certainly be closed as a duplicate of the above mentioned question, as even typing `George Snape ear` in the question title box brings up that question as a suggestion.

But as you can see, the accepted answer clearly doesn't answer the question.

What should happen in this case?

Comment: Make a new question. State in your question how that answer doesn't answer your question. Well make the linked question a duplicate of your question.

Comment: If you feel the current answer is inadequate, downvote it to obscurity and/or leave a comment explaining why it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I started a bounty for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: There is currently no accepted answer to the question; Mooz must have unaccepted it since you made this meta post.

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember why I accepted that particular answer to begin with. It might have been in my days where I accepted everything.

Comment: @Mooz Ah. To be young and able to click freely.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Does [tag:status-completed] apply here?

Comment: @ibid I wouldn't say so. The OP isn't asking for something to happen, they're just asking what their options are :)

Comment: Ask about it on meta and get it into Hot Meta Posts.  Enough people will see your meta post that links to the question, and someone will probably answer it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. **Start a bounty.** A few of the bounty reasons are applicable. *Authoritative Reference Needed*, *Canonical Answer Required*, and *Improve Details* would all make sense in this situation.
2. **Open a new question**, and be very clear in your question why your question is different. This is likely to draw *VTC - dupes*, and not in your favor. The exact question *was* asked. You're going to want to be more specific and detailed in your question and be ready to explain to VTC'ers why it shouldn't be duped.

Honestly, I'd just start a new bounty. This is exactly what bounties are for, and will result in less arguments. I'd also suggest talking to Mooz. He's an active user - both on the site and in chat. Find out why he thought the question was sufficiently answered. He may be willing to unaccept, or change the accepted answer if a new one comes in.

Comment: Don't talk to me, I'm grumpy AF and might bite you :p

Comment: @Mooz well, it's a good thing I didn't say, "he's a nice guy" like I almost did.